# Gesture detection inside ListView

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, gesture

I have some data to be displayed in a `ListView` (user needs to scroll to see everything). Some items inside the `ListView` should support gesture detection, in my case `onPanStart`, `onPanUpdate` and `onPanEnd`.

The purpose of this is to provide a timeline similar to Google Calendars, where there is a scrollable grid of dates/times, and the user can add an event on the grid and then drag across (modifying its height) to set its duration.

I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHZ0KSvTTqQ) as reference for the draggable item, and it works fine on its own, but as soon as I place it inside the `ListView` the drag gestures are no longer recognized and all I can do is scroll the `ListView`.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your `GestureDetector` is placed directly inside the `ListView` ?

Comment: It is not directly placed inside the `ListView`, the draggable items are placed inside table cells in a table, which is put inside the `ListView` (the table itself is also contained inside a container to add padding).

Comment: Then it makes sense that your widgets are not clickable, you can not click through top widgets

Comment: I see, but still, how could I achieve the desired functionality? Sorry if this seems stupid, I'm just getting started with Flutter.